# Showkey with cleveref and amsmath

Tags: amsmath, cleveref, showkeys

I have the following problem with `showkeys`. When use in combination with `cleveref` and `amsmath` the label for equation get some extraneous curly brackets. For example im compile the following the label for the equation will be `{test2}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}\label{test1}
\begin{equation}\label{test2}
\overline{a}=b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However, if a comment either `amsmath` or `cleveref` the label get fixed, i.e only `test2`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you should live with the extra braces.

Comment: If I don't use `amsmath` there is no `{...}` pair, even with `cleveref`

Comment: you are loading three packages _all_ of which redefine the label handling here. Since showkeys is just for draft usage I am, for once, inclined to agree with @egreg here.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading three packages all of which redefine the label handling here.

Since `showkeys` is just for draft usage and the extra braces are just in the draft label display not affecting the document typesetting I think it's safest not to try to catch this case in `showkeys` and simply ignore the extra braces.